# How to create an empty folder while creating a zip in gradle

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, war

i want to build the war file and include an empty folders like "classes" and "META-INF". I have the following code:

```
task buildWar(type: Zip){
    archiveName = 'myproject.war'
    includeEmptyDirs = true
    destinationDir = file("$targetDir/project")

    from("$root/grab/lib"){
        include "*.jar"
        into "WEB-INF/lib"
    }

}
```

I need to create "classes" and "META-INF". How i can do it inside buildWar task?

Comment: If you use `war` plugin it will be done automatically. Why do you create war file manually?

Comment: 'cause i need to provide some empty folders - btw i don't mine if you will provide me an example of war plugin usage

Comment: It's really easy, what you need is to apply that plugin, and have appropriate directory structure: http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/war_plugin.html.

Comment: @Opal not such a useful information actually - what if i want to collect more libs then one? where i can provide a destination? what if i want to create an empty folder here? more question than it was

Comment: Libraries will be added automatically from appropriate configurations. What destination do you mean? Empty folder, what for? Interesting attitude. I guess that almost 100% gradle users use the war plugin when constructing war and are able to alter it instead of building preparing war manually. Give the full scenario, it will be easier to help.

Comment: The web applications can be really different and difficult, these are not only WEB-INF and META-INF configs, what it web app is required for some special folder called "metadata" that is needed for statistics or what if customer wants to provide special folder "docs". WAR Gradle plugin doesn't have even an api to cover it. So the question is how to do it with the help of gradle task type ZIP?

Comment: You'll be astonished: it has. It's only the matter of putting *docs* folder e.g. under correct place in file tree. Nevermind. What can be done is to prepare the whole war structure in a temporary directory (along with empty dirs), then zip the whole directory and remove it.

Comment: A common case to do, but no easy approach can be found in gradle

Answer (score 0):

I use the following script to create a fat JAR, probably you could modify it to create WAR file:

```
//create a single Jar with all dependencies
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Project Name',
            'Implementation-Version': version,
            'Main-Class': 'org.foo.Bar'
  }
  baseName = project.name + '-all'
  from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
  with jar 
}
```

The manifest part above will generate your META-INF subfolder (where the manifest sits).

The `classes` folder will be auto-created by Gradle, if the project has Java files.